# Understrap wordpress starter theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to use understrap for my future theme and want to add swiperjs library to it, as said from the script official page, i have to add this from :

```
npm install swiper
```

After this what should i do? i have to require it from the gulpfile.js ?

```
var swiper = require('swiper');
console.log(swiper) // output the swiper object from terminal after gulp scripts
```

Inside the same file (gulpfile.js) i found a line where i can add my custom js :

```
    `${paths.dev}/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js`,

    // Adding currently empty javascript file to add on for your own themes´ customizations
    // Please add any customizations to this .js file only!
    `${paths.dev}js/custom-javascript.js`,
```

So i added 'custom-javascript.js' with just console.log('test') and alert('test') inside my src folder, and finaly run 'gulp scripts && gulp watch'

I don't get the console.log test nor the alert printed.

Someone could help me please ?

========== RESOLVED ===============

So for someone facing same issue, just add slash before the js directory :

```
`${paths.dev}/js/custom-javascript.js`
```

instead of :

```
`${paths.dev}js/custom-javascript.js`
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You could just run the JS and CSS from a CDN in the header.php file add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
```

and in the footer.php file add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for response but i want to merge scripts together, your method is not optimised. Loading js separately means http request for each script